# Python shell to pass commands as application input

Tags: python, linux, shell, operating-system, subprocess

Automation of manual process on Linux using Python shell.

I want to use python OS module to open an application and later pass commands one after another in the application opened.

```
import os
import subprocess
os.system('<app_name>')
subprocess.call('<app_input_command_1> && <app_input_command_2> && ... && <app_input_command_n>')
exit
```

This code is not able to pass the commands, just open the application.

Your inputs will be much appreciated.

Thanks for the anticipated help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open an application, and write to its input stream, you should use `subprocess` and `PIPE`:

```
...: import subprocess
...: p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...: out, _ = p.communicate(input=b'your commands\n')
...: print(out.decode())
your commands
```